# How to build a fast cache, fast searching for objects in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I got lots of data to write into database tables (Oracle).
Writing takes much time and I want to avoid to post data-sets which are in the table already. Therefor I need a cache.

At first I used generic List and Dictionary>key, value> as a cache.
I tried IMemoryCache from .NET but I got the feeling it does not fit on my problem.
Also I tried using hash, but that does not work because the object in my cache has a different has than a other object with same values.
My current solution is faster (nearly double speed) than posting every object into the database but still far to slow.
When I post a object to the database I get the key as return. This key I also need in the further code.

```
string dataRecordKey = dataRecord.MetaDataRecordId.ToString() + "|" + dataRecord.Profile + "|" + dataRecord.Group + "|" + dataRecord.FirstName + "|" + dataRecord.FamilyName+ "|" + dataRecord.City;
int dataRecordId = -1;
if (dictDataRecord.ContainsKey(dataRecordKey))
{
    dataRecordId = dictDataRecord[dataRecordKey];
}
else
{
    dataRecordId = await dataRecordRepository.CreateDataRecordAsync(dataRecord);
    dictDataRecord.Add(dataRecordKey, dataRecordId);
}
```

To post 115 data-sets costs 6 seconds.
To use my code above it takes 3.6 seconds.
But I need to get it below 1 second.

Comment: I think your problem is the way you are writing to Oracle.  115 writes per second is very slow.  You should be getting 1000s.  How are you writing to Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, problems like those are solved with hashing.

First

> Also I tried using hash, but that does not work because the object in my cache has a different has than a other object with same values

Did you override the hashing function? You can define how objects are hashed to a Dictionary, if the current hash doesn't fit your needs. First I recomend trying to override the hash:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  string dataRecordKey = dataRecord.MetaDataRecordId.ToString() + "|" + dataRecord.Profile + "|" + dataRecord.Group + "|" + dataRecord.FirstName + "|" + dataRecord.FamilyName+ "|" + dataRecord.City;
  return dataRecordKey.GetHashCode();
}
```

Now, if for some reason this hash is too expensive to compute the common solution is to **use multiple hashes!**:

- A fast, but unrealiable hash.
- A slow, but more reliable hash.

Use 2 hash sets (in C# simply use a Dictionary with any value you want, we will only care about whether the key exists or not, not the value)

For the first hashmap use the fast hash (for example, the length of the *dataRecordKey* string or just the length on one of its individual strings such as *dataRecord.FamilyName* or simply `dataRecord.GetHashCode()`

*To make a check:*

First, check for the record on the first (fast) dictionary. If the key is found on the first dictionary, well, remember that the hash is bad so we need to check the second dictionary using the aforementioned hash override.

If the key is not found on the second dictionary, then add it to second dictionary and to database. If its found on second, skip it.

If the key is **not found in the first dictionary** then **you are absolutely sure** it wasn't added to the database. Add it and then add to both hashmaps.

How many collisions the first hash has will afect performance. You'll be trading collisions for computation speed.

**Edit**
You say you need the key, so both Dictionaries can have the key as value. Just remember **do not retrieve the key from the first hashmap**, as multiple records will hash into the same value (which is intended).

**Edit 2**
Sorry, a little optimization, if nothing is found on the first dictionary you don't even need to check the second because you are sure its not there.

Also, to prevent lots of items in the same bucket, for the first dictionary, use a `bool` set to either true or false, the value is irrelevant.

Comment: Edited because the point of using the 2 hashes is to skip the slow whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution looks like that:

```
            int dataRecordId = -1;
            string dataRecordKey = dataRecord.MetaDataRecordId.ToString() + "|" + dataRecord.Profile + "|" + dataRecord.Group + "|" + dataRecord.FirstName + "|" + dataRecord.FamilyName+ "|" + dataRecord.City;
            int theHash = dataRecordKey.GetHashCode();
            if(dictDataRecord1.ContainsKey(theHash))
            {
                dataRecordId = dictDataRecord1[theHash];
            }
            else
            {
                dataRecordId = await dataRecordRepository.CreateDataRecordAsync(dataRecord);
                dictDataRecord1.Add(theHash, dataRecordId);
            }
```

Now it is **only a little faster**. 2.75 instead of 3.6 seconds per data set.

@André Santos: You speak about two Dictionarys. Do you mean two Dictionary object with the same content? That makes no sense in my eyes. Or the first Dictionary with (dataRecordKey.Length, dataRecordId)?